# call angular js 1 one controller in another controller notwroking

Tags: angularjs

```
.state('app.dashboard', {
  url: '/app/dashboard',
  templateUrl: '<%=path "form.html" %>',
  controller: 'formController as form'
})
```

I want to call another controller inside `form.html` on specific div.

If form.app is true then apply another controller else apply this controller default `formController`

**form.html**

```
<div ng-if="form.app" class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group1 margin-over">
  <div ng-controller="TestCTRL as test" ng-include="Template.url"></div>
</div>
```

can someone give me hint how can I achieve this?

Comment: add the controller to the `Template.url` file

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka not working i have already tried but not working Sir.
any other option sir?

Comment: Why don't you use a service?

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka it is giving me error Sir

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda How can i achieve this sir.
Can you please explain me?

Comment: A good tutorial can be found at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda i don't want to pass data sir. I want to apply controller on specific div. inside another controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with normal controller pattern for child/inside controller as follow:

```
<div ng-if="form.app" class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group1 margin-over">
    <div ng-controller="TestCTRL" ng-include="Template.url"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Unknown provider: applicationProvider <- application <- TeformController
this error give me sir When I am applying your answer sir

Comment: sorry i didn't get you.  ```if form.app is true then apply another controller else apply this controller default formController```
So you want eaither anotherController or formController but not both at a time, right? 
Or you want anotherController if `formController.app === true` ??

Comment: Thanx brother:-)

Answer (score 1):

The best way I suggest, is to use a service. Since that approach was looked down in the comments, the next approach would be to use events,

```
function FirstController($scope) {
   $scope.$emit('myEvent', args);
}

function SecondController($scope) {
   $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, args) {});
}
```

But it also seems to me you are looking for directives, 
In that case angular docs has a good example, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thanx brother:-)